# how to get cert from pem file for asp.net mvc application

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, pem

I have a pem file(gc.pem) from Google Cloud and it has

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
base64ecoded stuff(able to read)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I want to create pfx from this pem file to get my asp.net application working but unable to get certificate from this pem file; my attempts are:

```
openssl rsa -noout -text -in gc.pem
unable to load Private Key 8680:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:691:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

`openssl rsa -in gc.pem -out gckey.pem->` same as above

`openssl x509 -in gc.pem -text` -> this gives big details of `Date`, `Version`, `Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption`, `Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption Public-Key: (2048 bit)`,   `Modulus:, Exponent`

Google has not made documentation steps for generating cert. Their support executives don't know about it and they forward me sslhopper links to play with openssl.

i am not able to get private key & cer/crt(dont know); the only output is `pem->der & der->pem;` so much tricky google has made and does not have support. RSA cert or X509 cert ? what format / encryption... It seems 1. I don't know fundamental understanding and 2. google has made it very tricky as  if I supply commands in a proper sequence then only key pair cert can be generated. feeling lost after so many utilities (online decoder etc) since past one week... huuuff. please help .

Comment: Do you have a second file that starts with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`?

Comment: You need to put private key together with certificate in order to get PFX. We have no idea how you generated the key pair for that certificate.

Comment: @bartonjs, no, I received only one file .pem from Google which is --- BEGIN CERTIFICATE...END CERTIFICATE---; and when I generate a new key using ---openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048--- and using----openssl x509 -outform der -in your-cert.pem -out your-cert.crt---- to generate crt and then online tool sslhopper to get pfx; i get error as certificate and private key does not match.... please help whether rsa commands or x509 commands would work and how to get cert & private key both from the .pem file; thnx

Comment: @Crypt32 how to get private key from the Google .pem file; pls read my question ; i have not generated any thing; i just got pem file from google...

Comment: You can’t (unless you’re extraordinarily lucky) generate a private key to match. If you lost your private key you will need to make a new one and request a new cert. So really the question becomes “how did you get/request the certificate?” since a private key was needed at that stage by someone.

Comment: i got this certiificate from GSuite control panel "Download Certificate" button  with delete button(if you want to change your certificate); and it can generate multiple certificate for me but at a time I can use one certificate and that certificate should match with the update Gsuite application metadata; and every time it gives me .pem file; so there is a way to get PK and cer/crt/der smth; and combine both and then get pfx; this much only I understood in a week; but what exactly command tht I am asking I have tried approx 200 cmds ; all weird... cant upload pk; or pk & cer does not match;